# How to exclude business days from date calculations

Tags: pandas, numpy, date, datetime, calculation

Dates are in the following format:

`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Using the following notebooks and calculation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import datetime as dt

F52_metrics['Dock to UPS SAP Receipt'] = (F52_metrics['UPS SAP Receipt Date'].dt.date - F52_metrics['Dock Date'].dt.date).astype(str).map(lambda x: x.rstrip('00:00:00.000000000')).str.replace("NaT", "").str.replace("+","").str.replace("days","")
```

Need to replicate the above calculation to exclude business days. I have tried replacing calculation entirely with numpy.busday_count but have been experiencing syntax errors.

Comment: what do you define as a business day?  In some companies I've worked at only New Years day is recognised as a none business day.  Saturday's are business days in some locales and Friday's are holidays in others

Comment: M-F are business days

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy calendar.

```
def calendar(): 
    #set work week mask and optional holidays array
    return np.busdaycalendar(weekmask='1111100', holidays=['2020-01-01','2020-01-20','2020-02-17','2020-05-25','2020-07-03','2020-09-07','2020-10-12','2020-11-11','2020-11-26','2020-12-25'])

def countWeekDays(fromDate='2020-03-03', toDate='2020-06-03'):  
    d = np.arange(fromDate, toDate, dtype=np.datetime64)
    
    weekdays = d[np.is_busday(d, busdaycal=calendar())] 
    
    workDays = [(m, np.array([i for i in weekdays if i.item().month==m]).size) for m in range(1,13)]
    
    return workDays #weekdays, months #

>>> countWeekDays()
[(1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 21), (4, 22), (5, 20), (6, 2), (7, 0), (8, 0), (9, 0), (10, 0), (11, 0), (12, 0)]
```